# Calculating the area of region of the sky

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, geometry

I am given the right ascensions ($\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$) and declinations ($\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$) of a specific region of the sky. How can we find the area of this region? I know that there must be a cosine term in the calculation, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Hi  I'm not saying this is off topic but would you consider posting this on the astronomy and/or maths forums?  imo it's more likely to be answered fully there. Regards

Comment: How accurate do you need it and how big approximately is the area? Is is it like a hemisphere or a square degree.

Comment: can you post a diagram?

Comment: @irishphysics Astronomy is on-topic here, and the answer might not be of purely mathematical character.

Comment: @Thriveth. Hi....Newbie error on my part, I should have looked at the tag list first but I learned from the answer given. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean the region $\{(\alpha,\delta) : \alpha_1\leq \alpha\leq \alpha_2, \delta_1\leq \delta\leq \delta_2\}$. Measuring $\alpha$ and $\delta$ in radians, we can find the desired formula by integrating in spherical coordinates:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\alpha_1}^{\alpha_2} \int_{\delta_1}^{\delta_2} \cos \delta\ d\delta\ d\alpha
&=\int_{\alpha_1}^{\alpha_2} \sin\delta|_{\delta_1}^{\delta_2} \ d\alpha \\
&= \int_{\alpha_1}^{\alpha_2} (\sin{\delta_2}-\sin{\delta_1})\ d\alpha\\
&= (\alpha_2-\alpha_1)(\sin{\delta_2}-\sin{\delta_1})
\end{align*}
This gives the area of the region on the unit sphere (where the entire unit sphere has area $4\pi$).

Comment: This is correct only on distances so short that we can neglect cosmological expansion.